# Undefined method 'join' during mysql action (ruby/sinatra)

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

Undefined method 'join' during mysql action (ruby/sinatra)

Code:

```
  rs = con.query('select * from userlog')
  @logentry = ""
  rs.each_hash { |h|  
    @logentry = @logentry + "ID: " + h['Id'] + "User: " + h['user'] + " - Time: " + h['datetime'] + " - Description: " + h['description'] + "<br>"
    }
```

Error:

```
undefined method `join' for #<String:0x007f70585b68f8>
```

when I add ".to_s" to the "h[Id]" then I get blank results for the ID but the rest is shown.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your 'userlog' table column name for the identifier is not 'Id', maybe 'id'. Otherwise it would have been selected normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The reason was that table name was incorrect in database, and for some reason MySQL error messages were incorrect. Check all database, table and variable names.